# Java.nio.files - Copying files

Tags: java, file, copying, java.nio.file

Can anyone tell me what I've done wrong with the following code. I receive no errors - it just goes straight to the catch.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Path source = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\SamplePictures");
    Path nwdir = Paths.get("D:\\NetbeansProjects\\CopyingFiles\\copiedImages");

    try{
    Files.copy(source, nwdir);
    }catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println("Unsucessful. What a surprise!");
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you print out e.getMessage() in the catch, then it might tell you.

Comment: If you print your stacktrace, you might have a better clue as to what is going on. Add e.printStackTrace(System.out) into your catch block.

Comment: Have you tried, for example, `e.printStackTrace()` ? You'll get a better description of the problem.

Comment: You `receive no errors` because you ignored them. ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you take a look at the Javadocs of [Files.copy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...%29), you'll notice this line (emphasis added):

> If the file is a directory then it creates an empty directory in the target location (*entries in the directory are not copied*). This method can be used with the walkFileTree method to copy a directory and all entries in the directory, or an entire file-tree where required.

So it looks like you need to use that walkFileTree method.

(And as the commenters said, print out exceptions and they'll often tell you what's wrong!)

Comment: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\Users\Public\Pictures\SamplePictures
 at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:79)
 at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
 at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:102)
 at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileCopy.copy(WindowsFileCopy.java:99)
 at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.copy(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:277)
 at java.nio.file.Files.copy(Files.java:1219)
 at Main.main(Main.java:14)

Comment: That's nice, but, as I said, your code will not work because you're trying to do a recursive copy with a function that cannot do recursive copies. Take a look at the API link that I provided.

Comment: By recursive copy, do you mean the directory and the files and directories within samplepictures. If so - I have changed the path to link directly to a single .jpg file with the same error. Apologies if im missing your point.

Comment: No problem. What did you end up doing to fix it?

Comment: The directory "Sample pictures" had a space in it. I thought java would complain because of the spaces, so I renamed it "SamplePictures". However, this didn't update the path. Another problem that occurred was my nwdir. I thought the path would be where I wanted the file. This is correct, but it also needs the file name.

Answer (score 4):

Came across here looking for a NIO Java7 approach to recursively copy a directory to another location. This can be done with `Files.walkFileTree` as Jon7 mentioned in the other anwer. This code I got for a simple directory copy:

```
final Path srcDir, final Path dstDir;
Files.walkFileTree(srcDir, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
    public FileVisitResult visitFile( Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs ) throws IOException {
        return copy(file);
    }
    public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory( Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs ) throws IOException {
        return copy(dir);
    }
    private FileVisitResult copy( Path fileOrDir ) throws IOException {
        Files.copy( fileOrDir, dstDir.resolve( srcDir.relativize( fileOrDir ) ) );
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }
});
```

For a more detailed example which also handles file attributes and overwriting of existing files, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/examples/Copy.java .

Comment: Beware that `srcDir.relativize( fileOrDir )` will throw a `ProviderMismatchException` if you use this to copy across different file systems, for example, from a ZipFile to default.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I have managed to copy a file from one location to another:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import static java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption.*;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class App  {

 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
    Path source = Paths.get("E:/myFile.pdf");
    Path nwdir = Paths.get("F:");
    try
    { 
       Files.copy(source, nwdir.resolve(source.getFileName()), REPLACE_EXISTING);
       System.out.println("File Copied");
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }

}
```